# I Asked a Yes/No Question That Was Then Closed For Being Too General? Why?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

The question was accompanied by a detailed explanation to ensure that the question was clear, but the question was still yes/no. Why was it closed by jordan.baucke, Peter Knolle and Saariko?

The question was: Does a Prerequisite Tree (Described in Detail Inside) Exist for Beginning/Self-Taught Developers?

This is clearly a yes/no question, regardless of how detailed the explanation was. Just because Abhinav Gupta is "scared to read such essays, since my school days. Please cut down the fat – Abhinav Gupta," doesn't that mean he should just move on to a question that is more suited to his abilities?

Plenty of questions are accompanied by hundreds of lines of code, yet this one, which is accompanied by an (admittedly) lengthy explanation, but is still a yes/no question, closed as being too general?

Jordan Bauke said that "this board is more related to specific questions regarding the use of and development on the SFDC platform. – jordan.baucke," however, I think this question is very clearly related to learning how to develop on the SFDC platform.

Here's a link to the question: [Creating a Prerequisite Tree for beginning/self-taught developers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/does-a-prerequisite-tree-described-in-detail-inside-exist-for-beginning-self-t#comment1630_1400)

Can this question be re-opened?

Thanks

Comment: I invite you to try and break your original question, try to create even several small subjected, narrow questions, that can be answerable. Don't feel discouraged. The fact that a question was closed has nothing personal. It's just trying to keep the site to it's aim and structure.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you did a great thing by bringing this discussion here to meta. That's one of its explicit purposes, and I hope the conversation here is helpful for you!

Answer (score 3):

I read through the description and by the time I got to the end it seemed to me that it was more about starting a discussion:

> Thanks for hearing me out, and feel free to contact me with any questions or thoughts that this may have stirred up.

But you are right, I looked at just the question part again, and that is definitely a yes/no question, so I was wrong to vote to close it.  I am admitting I was wrong and am for opening it back up.  Sorry and thank you for very much for bringing it up.

Comment: Although the question itself is yes/no, the rest of the (rather large) body is definitely tending towards a discussion.

Comment: @LaceySnr - I agree.  That's why I had voted to close it.  By the time that I got done reading the description (especially the last sentence that I quoted being the final takeaway from the question) it seemed way more like a discussion to me, but I think the question itself is just a yes/no so jackermann is right to question why I (and the others) voted to close it and based on that reasoning I feel I was wrong.  Incidentally, the last sentence about contacting him seems weird...almost like a business opportunity or something, but I'd have no way of knowing that.

Comment: My take on this is that although you can answer the question with a simple yes or no, it wouldn't have been accepted as a satisfactory answer because @jackerman09 really was looking for more discussion on the matter.

Comment: Although there is a yes/no component to this question, I think it's perfectly reasonable to close it and advise as to why something so needlessly lengthy and rambling isn't appropriate or otherwise in alignment with the spirit of the site. There are guidelines around comments and when they become more of a 1-on-1 dialog than a complementary aspect of the main thread. Similarly, pushing out large sections of personal commentary, loosely related to an original question seems fine to carve out of the site, imo.

Comment: While I was not looking for a discussion, you're right in that I was looking for more than yes/no. If the answer was 'yes', I was hoping that the answerer would point me in the direction of the existing 'tree' so that I could use it to help learn Force.com development in a more organized way.

Answer (score 2):

I had to lock your question. Indeed, after the anonymous user edit, it doesn't look anymore like a yes/no answer, however, looking on the scope of SFSE - your question is beyond it.

It looks like you are looking for a design idea, or something that looks more like a guide line on how to build a tree (of any kind) - and there is never a yes/no answer to it.

Yes, you are asking for: how to do it.... - but the answers I fear you will get will open a discussion, which I feel is not the correct place to have.

I want to note, your question is NOT locked because it's lengthy or detailed. We encourage users to have as much detail in the Q, in order for the answer to be as swift and as correct as possible.

Comment: I'm not looking for how to build it. I'm looking for an existing 'tree' so that I can learn Force.com development in a more organized way.